# Devise confirmation link is missing domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable

Devise confirmation_url is producing just a relative url with no domain such as:

```
http://users/confirmation?confirmation_token=...
```

I tried changing

```
confirmation_url(@resources, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token)
```

to

```
confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token)
```

but it produces the same url. I upgraded to devise 2.2.3 but same outcome. Rails 3.1.4

**Update:**
I have set in my production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysubdomain.mysite.com' }
```

and I tried setting

```
    before_filter set_actionmailer_host

    def set_actionmailer_host
      ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
    end
```

to no avail in application controller (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1567)

**Update:**
This occurs in both development and production.

**Update**
I can't understand why Devise isn't using the template in app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.haml If I could edit that I could append the host manually: `'http://mysite.com/' + confirmation_url(...`
I tried setting the scoped views setting but it didn't have any effect
This is a disaster, users can't confirm their registration :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have missed to add the default url hosts to your environment config-files. When you run the `rails g devise:install` command you usually receive those instructions.

```
# config/environments/development.rb

# Default actiomailer url host (required by devise) 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myapp.dev' }
```

You need this setting for all your environments.

```
# config/environments/production.rb

# Default actiomailer url host (required by devise) 
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myproductionapp.com' }
```

Comment: The :host_only parameter had actually been set in the confirmation_url call, which was causing the problem